# Business-oriented calendar app for OS X

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, calendar, google-calendar

I'm looking for a calendar app for OS X that shows available times for meeting attendees, and allows me to propose meetings and accept such proposals from others.

I've been trying Mac calendar and BusyCal, and neither of them meet my needs.

We're using Google app as our calendar server and although I can always use their web interface I prefer to use an installed application.

Comment: Both Calendar and BusyCal consult free-busy lists for environments that have servers to host that information. Are you perhaps looking for OS X server (or equivalent) to simply host that data. The calendaring software is ready to schedule and just needs some plumbing to provide the data.

Comment: Doesn't google app host busy/free information?

Comment: They don't serve it to clients for some reason. Perhaps they charge for it or expect you to give them web views so they can sell ads? You'd have to ask google to explain the reasoning.

Comment: I would recommend to not use Google Apps. This is the issue with what you are trying to accomplish. Their support for enterprise features is far less than what most other solutions use. Some great alternatives that support Mac environment: OS X Server, Exchange, Kerio, Zimbra. All of these solutions provide free/busy time visibility to the basic iCal/Calendar app on OS X, as well as Outlook:Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Exchange server, Outlook will do that. Calendar for OS X can do it too, provided your calendar server supports it.  OS X Server's Calendar server does.

In either use case the parties must be in the same organization or otherwise accessible due to federation.